# How Optimizers Vary when Changing Parameters in the Constraints

Tags: derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to solve the following comparative statics problem. Assume I have four choice variables, $x_{1}, x_{2}, y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$, and two parameters $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$. I have the following minimization problem,

\begin{align*}
\min_{x_{1}, x_{2}, y_{1},y_{2} \geq 0}   &K_{1}x_{1} + K_{2}x_{2} + y_{1}^{-\gamma} + y_{2}^{-\gamma} \\
&s.t \hspace{3pt} y_{j} - d_{ij}x_{i} \leq d_{ij}t_{i}   \hspace{3pt} \text{for} \hspace{3pt}i =1,2, j=1,2
\end{align*}

$K_{1},K_{2},\gamma, d_{ij} > 0$ are additional parameters that are not relevant to the question at hand.

I would like to understand how the optimal values of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ change, when only $t_{1}$ increases.

There are all of this monotone comparative statics results, however, my intuition is that the behavior should not be monotone. $x_{1}$ should weakly decrease and $x_{2}$ should weakly increase.

Any suggestions?

I edited the constraint because it read $y_{i}$, instead of $y_{j}$.

Comment: Currently, $t_1$ is only part of the two $i=1$ constraints. Since there is no connection (no common variable or parameter) between the $i=1$ and $i=2$ constraints, then $x_2$ is independent of $t_1$. And depending on the parameter values, even $x_1$ may not change, with the optimizer instead choosing to increase $y_1$.

Comment: Hi @TonyMathew , thanks for the suggestion. I do not think that is true, though. If $t_1$ changes this can have an effect on $x_2$ vía changes in $y_1$. I just noticed I had a typo in the constraint, which I just corrected.

Comment: Can someone please help me?